# how to iteratively extend pd.dataframe avoiding list overallocation?

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I often do

```
df_collection = []
for iteration in iterations:
   df_this_iteration = computational_step(*many_other_iteration_specific_params...)
   df_collection.append(df_this_iteration)
df_collection = pd.concat(df_collection,axis=0)
```

when `iterations` and/or `df_this_iteration` become large , the `df_collection.append` operation becomes very memory inefficient due to underlying list allocation memory.
How to improve or event vectorize this code to reduce memory footprint?

I read in High Performance Python
by Micha Gorelick and Ian Ozsvald

> When a list of size N is first appended to, Python must create a new
> list that is big enough to hold the original N items in addition to
> the extra one that is being appended. However, instead of allocating
> N+1 items, M items are actually allocated, where M > N, in order to
> provide extra headroom for future appends. Then, the data from the old
> list is copied to the new list and the old list is destroyed. The
> philosophy is that one append is probably the beginning of many
> appends, and by requesting extra space we can reduce the number of
> times this allocation must happen and thus the total number of memory
> copies that are necessary. This is quite important since memory copies
> can be quite expensive, especially when list sizes start growing.

Comment: Ok, so again, **what exactly is the problem**? Again, are you actually encountering a memory issue? Suppose the worst case you do `.append` on a list with size 1_000_000 that must resize, that would require an auxilliary 8 MB. Is that really an issue you are encountering?

Comment: if there is a way to avoid list overallocation as I am possibly running out of memory because of that

Comment: my list elements are were large 1_000_000 ->8MB only if floats?

Comment: The objects inside the list don't get copied. The buffer is just a buffer of PyObject pointers, so *whatrever* it is, it's 8 bytes per item. The size of the list elements is **totally irrelevant**. Again, unless you are in an embeded environment or something, then almost certainly, list-overallocation (or append requiring a copy of the underlying buffer periodically) are almost certianly not the fundamental issue

Comment: Also, over-allocation is almost certainly not the problem. As an implementation detail, using the `*` operator results in a list with no over-allocation. Consider: `mylist = []; mylist.extend((None for _ in range(1_000_000))); print(sys.getsizeof(mylist))` I'm getting `8448728`. And `sys.getsizeof([None]*1_000_000)` is giving `8000056`. So overallocation for a list of size 1 million is requiring `448672` bytes. Practically nothing on modern hardware. half a megabyte

Comment: ok... I should close the question, although I think what you shared is useful and could be captured

Comment: I can write a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

Overallocation is almost certainly not the problem you are encountering.

As an implementation detail, if you create a list using the `*` operator, or using a known-sized iterable, e.g. `range`, then it will allocate exactly:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> mylist = [None] * 1_000_000
>>> sys.getsizeof(mylist)
8000056
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist.extend((None for _ in range(1_000_000)))
>>> sys.getsizeof(mylist)
```

So in the worst-case of over-allocation, you require an extra:

```
>>> f"{(8448728 - 8000056)*1e-3:,} kilobytes"
'448.672 kilobytes'
```

So I doubt that is the cause of your issue.

A **key fact to understand**, the underlying buffer that is copied is a primitive array of `Py_Object` pointers. So it's a machine-word per item in the list, the actual size of the objects *doesn't matter*, they can be `int`, `str`, `float`, `pd.DataFrame` objects, they all only require the 8-byte pointer (on a 64bit system) when the buffer is copied.

So, when the `.append` does requires copying the whole buffer, it's still just:

```
>>> f"{(8448728)*1e-6:,} megabytes"
'8.448728 megabytes'
```

Again, I highly doubt this is the cause of your problem.

In any case, you can always *pre-allocate*, so something like:

```
df_collection = [None]*len(iterations)
for i, iteration in enumerate(iteration):
    df_collection[i] = omputational_step(*many_other_iteration_specific_params...)
```

But again, I doubt this will materially affect your situation (and note, it relies on implementation details).